# Finding cyclic paths using Gremlin along with normal paths

Tags: gremlin

I am using NeptuneDB with 2M edges and vertices. The graph can have cycles of length 3-10 and is highly connected.

While fetching the downstream for a particular NodeId is am running the query

```
g.V(currentNode).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(0).or().loops().is(12)).path().toList();
```

The issue here is that by using **simplePath()** the cyclic nodes are getting filtered out.

For ex: in case of 1->2->3->1, I am only getting 1->2->3 in the pathList but I want the pathList to contain the first node in case of cycles, i.e. 1->2->3->1.
I have been looking a lot for a way to model the query which will return me both cyclic and non-cylic path for the downstream but no luck.

I am also facing issues of memory timeout due to **simplePath()** and **Path()** step as I know they are costly operation but I can't seem to find my way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find `cyclicPaths` as well as non cyclic ones, rather than do

```
g.V(currentNode).
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
  until(outE().count().is(0).or().loops().is(12)).
  path().
  toList();
```

You might try something like

```
g.V(currentNode).
  repeat(out()).
  until(or(__.not(out()),loops().is(12),cyclicPath())).
  path().
  toList();
```

This will include cyclic paths in the result. You will be able to spot them as the first and last vertex in the path result will be the same.

In a highly connected graph you may need to add a `limit` step to stop trying to find all possible results as there could be many.